# Angular Monaco Editor - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type : Error while i chnaged My angular version from 12 to 16

Tags: angular, npm, deployment, monaco-editor, ngx-monaco-editor

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/browser/viewParts/minimap/minimap.css:7:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| /* START cover the case that slider is visible on mouseover */

> .monaco-editor .minimap.slider-mouseover .minimap-slider {
> |       opacity: 0;
> |       transition: opacity 100ms linear;

I have tried in many ways but it didn't worked to resolve the issues, I hope you guys will help me resolve it. Thank you.